# Greasemonkey Hijack setInterval

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to build a greasemonkey script for adding smilies to a chatbox.

I need to detect the refresh of the chatbox and replace the smilies:
The chatbox refreshes with a setInterval on the page:

```
setInterval(refreshChat, 7000);
```

Normaly I would hijack this in this way

```
var refreshChat = unsafeWindow.refreshChat;
unsafeWindow.refreshChat = function() {
    doSmileyReplace();
    return refreshChat();
};
```

But for some reason this doesn't register?
I tried setting my own interval in the greasemonkey to run 5 miliseconds later then the setinterval on the page itself, it works, but doesnt look right.

the refreshChat function is nothing special

```
function refreshChat() {
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*500000);
    $('#chat').load('chat.php?cachebuster='+randomnumber+'&method=chat');
}
```

**So how do I catch the setInterval?**

Answer (score 0):

`$('#chat').load(` makes an ajax call.  You are replacing the smilies prior to the AJAX call returning.  If it is acceptable to just replace `refreshChat` all together than you can just add a complete function on the `load`:

```
$('#chat').load('chat.php?cachebuster='+randomnumber+'&method=chat',doSmileyReplace);
```

Comment: Looking at it further, even without the mentioned `load` issue, wouldn't you want to call `refreshChat` first and then `doSmileyReplace`?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use this:

```
var script = refreshChat.toString();
script.replace('&method=chat');','&method=chat');mycoolhijecfunc();')
refreshChat = eval('('+script+')')
```

where `mycoolhijecfunc` is the function that adds the smilies.

got this from messing in the source of [TWpro](http://tw-pro.de/) , I was stunned to see it work, I modified it it normally is:

```
var modify_function = function (obj, method, options) {
    try {
        //if (console && console.log) console.log("TW Pro: Modifying method " + method);
        if (!obj || !obj[method]) return;
        var func = obj[method].toString();
        for (var i=3; i<arguments.length; i++) {
            if (arguments[i] && arguments[i].length > 1) {
                var replacement = arguments[i][1],
                    arg_opts = arguments[i][2] || {};
                if (typeof replacement == "function") {
                    replacement = "(" + replacement.toString() + ")()";
                }
                if (arg_opts.catch_errors) {
                    replacement = ";try{" + replacement + "}catch(twpro_exception){window.twpro_debug.log(twpro_exception,'method " + method + "')}";
                }
                if (arg_opts.escape) {
                    replacement = replacement.replace(/\$/g, "$$$$");
                }
                switch (arg_opts.pos) {
                    case "L":
                        replacement += "$&";
                        break;
                    case "R":
                        replacement = "$&" + replacement;
                        break;
                }
                func = func.replace(arguments[i][0], replacement);
            }
        }
        //self.fncs.push('"'+method+'"', func);
        obj[method] = eval("(" + func + ")");
        if (options && options.bind) {
            obj[method] = obj[method].bind(options.bind);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        twpro_debug.log("TW Pro failed to modify function " + method + ": " + e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `refreshChat` won't work well, since the new messages are loaded asynchronously by AJAX.

Fortunately, the page uses jQuery, so triggering off that AJAX is easy.  You could do something like this:

```
/*--- Evesdrop on the page's AJAX calls and rewrite smilies after 
    a short delay.
*/
unsafeWindow.$('body').ajaxSuccess (
    function (event, requestData) {
        setTimeout (function() { doSmileyReplace (); }, 111);
    }
);
```

Note that the delay is *probably* not necessary, I put it there just in case.